# add Control on field date time

Tags: visual-studio, xml, spfield, sharepoint-fields, schema

Is there a way to add a control on field datetime in schema.xml file without javascript and without c#.
For exemple my date file cant be less than the current date .
od date 2 must be more than date 1.